# UITableView not reloading correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, reloaddata

I've been having this problem a lot where the table view either doesn't load the cells the first time or displays temporary labels. In both cases, when the table is loaded a second time (by another button in which I force it to reload or by going to the previous view in the app and going back to the table) everything shows up as it was supposed to.

Im using `[table reloadData]` to reload the table in the `viewDidAppear:` method as it didn't work in the `viewDidAppear:` method and in another case I put it in a button action.

I'm also using this method to set the label of the cell that I have placed in the storyboard:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [contactsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
    label.text = [Array3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

EDIT

I declare the array below the implementation like:
    NSMutableArray * Array3;
After that in the ViewDidLoad method I declare the rest of the array:
    Array3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];
Then I load the elements in the array by calling a function within the ViewDidLoad method to fill the array with elements.

EDIT 2
Showing more of how I populate the array
- (void)viewDidLoad {

```
[super viewDidLoad];
Array3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];
 [self loadArray];

}
- (void) loadArray
//populate array in here.
// I use the add object method
//  [Array3 addobject:object];
{
```

Comment: Where do you load/define/fill Array3? Your description suggests to me that the datasource is getting filled in async and isn't ready when you first come into showing the view controller.

Comment: I'm defining it below my implementation in the .m file. Do you know how I might fix it?

Comment: No way for me to tell you because you don't show it. :-) How does that array get elements?

Comment: Please check the sentence *Im using [table reloadData] to reload the table in the viewDidAppear: method as it didn't work in the viewDidAppear: method and in another case I put it in a button action.*, specifically your `viewDidAppear` comment.

Comment: "Then I load the elements in the array by calling a function within the ViewDidLoad method to fill the array with elements." That doesn't tell anyone the details of **how** you load the array (such as whether it is synchronous or not). Show the method that you call inside viewDidLoad. Show your viewDidLoad method so we can see _where_ you call the method that loads the array.

Comment: Brad, I've edited my post.

Comment: What about running [contactsTableView reloadData]; after [self loadArray]; in viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Good news first: Your method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is correct.
2. There is no need to invoke `reloadData` in neither `-viewDidAppear:` nor `-viewWillAppear`. This remark may not hold true if you modify the content of **Array3** while your view is covered, which is a special case.

It is not a matter of where you define your method, but where you invoke it. A reasonable place to populate the content of **Array3** is in

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
```

or

```
override func viewDidLoad()
```

**Pitfalls**

Additionally, you need all your delegate methods (`numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) to be returning consistent values, in accordance to your array. A simple technique is to use the number of entries in the array to drive `numberOfRowsInSection`.

**When to use reloadData?**

A typical use of `reloadData` is shown below:

```
- (void)loadArray {
    //populate array in here.
    ...
    [self.tableview reloadData]; // Possibly postpone to main thread
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on "required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)?" I've never seen this before (I'm using Obj-C)

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to populate my array in the -(void)loadView method, but I cant get it to work. Now, the table doesn't even show up at all when I place the code inside that method rather than the ViewDidLoad. Is there anything I should be doing inside the ViewDidLoad too?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Array3` is nil When the first load.

Comment: Yes it is initially set to nil, but I fill it with objects in the ViewDidLoad method right after I set up the array. I've edited my post to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Give the cell identifier unique for example you can

`NSString *cellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormate:@"%d",indexPath.row];`

Maybe this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in your initial set up for `Array3` you must allocate this variable to memory to then be used in a different function, like the `tableView:cellForIndexPath:`

Therefore instead of `Array3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];` you would use `Array3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Since you're leaving it as an empty array on this line of code, you would not use `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];` because it is literally the same deal